# Create Invoice By Code

Tags: c#, cloud, erp, acumatica

I am using this code to create new Invoice. I do customization in from SOInvoiceEntry. I debugged and get an error Revision ID is not empty. I guest that this code could not get information of customer's financial information  when I set value for customerID. Here is my code. Thanks for your support.

```
public PXAction<ARInvoice> preparePayment;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pay Invoice", Enabled = true)]
    [PXButton()]
    public IEnumerable PreparePayment(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<ARRegister> doclist = new List<ARRegister>();
        SOOrderShipment soOrderShipment =
                     PXSelect
                         <SOOrderShipment,
                             Where<SOOrderShipment.invoiceNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.invoiceNbr>>>
                             >.Select(new PXGraph(), Base.Document.Current.RefNbr);

        if (soOrderShipment != null)
        {
            SOOrder soOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr,
                Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(
                    new PXGraph(), soOrderShipment.OrderNbr, soOrderShipment.OrderType);
            SOOrderExt soExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(soOrder);
            if (soExt.CustomerID != soExt.UsrARCustomer)
            {
                ARInvoiceEntry arInvoiceGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
                ARInvoice invoice = (ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].CreateInstance();
                invoice = (ARInvoice) arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof (ARInvoice)].Insert(invoice);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.customerID>(invoice,soExt.UsrARCustomer);

                invoice.DocType = ARInvoiceType.DebitMemo;
                invoice.CustomerID = soExt.UsrARCustomer;
                //invoice.CustomerID = Base.Document.Current.CustomerID;
                Location location =
                    PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>.Select(
                        arInvoiceGraph, soExt.UsrARCustomer);
                if(location!=null)
                       arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.customerLocationID>(invoice, location.LocationID);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValueExt<ARInvoice.docDate>(invoice, DateTime.Now);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.projectID>(invoice,location.CDefProjectID);

                ARInvoice oldInvoice = (ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].CreateCopy(invoice);

                invoice.CuryOrigDocAmt = 0;
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].RaiseRowUpdated(invoice, oldInvoice);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt>(invoice, invoice.CuryDocBal);
                invoice.RefNoteID = 1;

                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValueExt<ARInvoice.hold>(invoice, false);

                doclist.Add((ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Current);
                arInvoiceGraph.Save.Press();

            }


        }
```

}

Comment: "is not empty" or "may not be empty" ? Because with reflector I see only "may not be empty"

Comment: @Yura: Sorry may not be empty is correct error

Comment: do you have some code for ARInvoice_RowPersisting in your extension graph?

Comment: @Yura: I don't have customization for this event

Answer (score 0):

As far as I look inside `protected virtual void ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)` in base graph, I see some error messages there, which says `"may not be empty"`. There is not any code which has relation to RevisionID. But there is a code which has RevisionID in DAC class `ARInvoice`, fields `BillAddressID, BillContactID`. From this facts I propose you to check do you put correct ID for ARAddress in `ARInvoice` and check whether in db table ARAddress has values in column RevisionID. That is required due to fact that RevisionID in class ARAddress is declared in the following way:

```
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault]
    public virtual int? RevisionID
    {
      get
      {
        return this._RevisionID;
      }
      set
      {
        this._RevisionID = value;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I will check it again and reply to you. Thanks for your support

Comment: pls, check my answer above

Comment: First of all congratulations with moving one step forward. I'll try find time tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
 arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.customerID>(invoice,soExt.UsrARCustomer);
```

Try this

```
invoice.Customer = soExt.UsrARCustomer;
invoice = arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Update(invoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for saving Document data by change code like this

```
 public IEnumerable PreparePayment(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<ARRegister> doclist = new List<ARRegister>();
        SOOrderShipment soOrderShipment =
                     PXSelect
                         <SOOrderShipment,
                             Where<SOOrderShipment.invoiceNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.invoiceNbr>>>
                             >.Select(new PXGraph(), Base.Document.Current.RefNbr);

        if (soOrderShipment != null)
        {
            SOOrder soOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr,
                Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                And<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(
                    new PXGraph(), soOrderShipment.OrderNbr, soOrderShipment.OrderType);
            SOOrderExt soExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(soOrder);
            if (soExt.CustomerID != soExt.UsrARCustomer)
            {
                BAccount bAccount = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID,Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(),soExt.UsrARCustomer);
                ARInvoiceEntry arInvoiceGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
                ARInvoice invoice = (ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].CreateInstance();
                invoice = (ARInvoice) arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof (ARInvoice)].Insert(invoice);
                // Using SetValueExt by Passing AcctCD
arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValueExt<ARInvoice.customerID>(invoice,bAccount.AcctCD);
                invoice.CustomerID = soExt.UsrARCustomer;
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.docDesc>(invoice, "N/A");
                invoice.DocType = ARInvoiceType.DebitMemo;

                Location location =
                    PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>>>.Select(
                        arInvoiceGraph, soExt.UsrARCustomer);
                if(location!=null)
                       arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.customerLocationID>(invoice, location.LocationID);

                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Update(invoice);
                ARInvoice oldInvoice = (ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].CreateCopy(invoice);

                invoice.CuryOrigDocAmt = Base.Document.Current.CuryOrigDocAmt;
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].RaiseRowUpdated(invoice, oldInvoice);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValue<ARInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt>(invoice, invoice.CuryDocBal);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].SetValueExt<ARInvoice.hold>(invoice, false);
                arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Update(invoice);
                doclist.Add((ARInvoice)arInvoiceGraph.Caches[typeof(ARInvoice)].Current);
       // Insert transaction data
                ARTran arTran = new ARTran();
                arTran.TranDesc = "Total Value";
                arTran.Qty = 1;
                arTran.UnitPrice = Base.Document.Current.CuryDocBal;
                arTran.CuryLineAmt = Base.Document.Current.CuryDocBal;
                arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
                ARTran arTranUpdated = (ARTran) arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Update(arTran);
                arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Current = arTranUpdated;
                arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Cache.Update(arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Current);
                arInvoiceGraph.Save.Press();

            }


        }
```

Although Document data is saved, the transactions data is not. I have tried this code to create it and I got and error. Do you have any suggestion for this? Thank you for your supporting

```
 AR Error #113: Cannot save notes.

   at PX.Objects.AR.InvoiceNbrAttribute.RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceNbrAttribute.RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisted(Object item, PXDBOperation operation, PXTranStatus tranStatus, Exception exception)
   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistInserted(PXCache sender, Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntry.Persist()
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__0.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious about

```
arInvoiceGraph.Transactions.Current = arTranUpdated;
```

According to T200 manual:
You can set the
Currentproperty in the following cases:
• To be able to process multiple data records by a graph (see Example 9.2: Implementing the
Receipt Release Operation).
• To be able to open a page displaying the specified data record when you redirect to the page from
another one (see Example 3.4: Adding a Redirection Link to the Grid).

I not sure, that in your case you do point 1 or 2.

Comment: Hi Yura, I will check it

Comment: I d not mean about redirect. I have found that in PM module in PMBilling Engine I found that they use PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(invoiceEntry.Caches[typeof(ARTran)], newTran, data.Note); I have try but another bug that is Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: it means you missed initialization of some value

Comment: I dont know what values that I have missed. I am trying to figure out

Comment: I have add value and it back to an error   AR Error #113: Cannot save notes. I dont know why although have used code to initialize note value.

Comment: I found that the value is store for NoteID in ARRegister is -2147483647 so when insert into ARInvoice it cannot get value from this.